# Compare against a special character

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

I am attempting to compare a TD table cell value (currently "& #9650;" without the space), but no matter what I try I can not get it to compare correctly.  I have tried the following ways:

```
nodeValue
innerHTML
innerText
textContext
```

For example:

```
if (Cell.textContext == "&#9650;") { alert('got it'); }
```

But I can't get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATED

The HTML is as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&#9650;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the html. Would be helpful with verifying in a snippet.

Comment: Is the cell content text encoded/decoded appropriately to compare it to it's html entity ?

Comment: `console.log(Cell.textContext)` and see what it really contains...

Comment: @JJ It logs as 'undefined', however if I do an alert it will show the symbol.  And the cell also shows the symbol.

Comment: That sounds unlikely, but if the alert shows the character and not `&#9650;` then obviously you should be comparing to the character instead (i.e. compare to *exactly* what the alert shows.)

Comment: Also note that `&larr;` and `&#9650;` are completely different characters.

Comment: @JJJ sorry, I copied the wrong td value for the post (updated).  It was comparing against the 9650 and not the larr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing using the [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) function :

`if (unescape(Cell.textContent) == "▲") { alert('got it'); }`

Comment: `unescape` works only for URL encoded characters, not for HTML entities.

Comment: upvoted as it answers the OPs question in that all he/she wanted to do was make comparison against the triangle unicode symbol.

Comment: This worked.  And per JJJ's comment, I had to compare against the symbol itself, not against the character's text.  Thanks Jeff!

Comment: And just as a follow-up, it didn't even require the unescape() call.  I just needed to compare against the symbol itself.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the same as Jeff Noels but I stored the contents into variables and made the comparison with variables as well as let the triangle render to the page before then making a comparison.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{ 
    const main = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(main);
    main.innerHTML = `&#9650`;
    const parsedtriangle = unescape(main.innerHTML);
    if (main.innerHTML == parsedtriangle){
        console.log('comparison worked');
    }
});
```